# Setting Parameters for Modules With Conditions

Tags: ansible

Assume you have a list of guest users for your servers and you want to make sure that they are only present on the unimportant hosts group `playground`.

Naively I would do it like that, which doesn't work:

```
- name: adding guest users to playground servers
  user: >
      name="{{item.key}}"
      shell="{{item.value.shell}}"
      groups="{{item.value.groups}}"
      state="{{'present' if host in playground else 'absent'}}" #tricky part
  with_dict: guests
```

How to achieve that goal successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list `group_names` contains all groups the current host belongs to.
So your condition should look like this:

```
{{'present' if 'playground' in group_names else 'absent'}}
```